Comparing distances between multiple points?
I have this spatial data set in R:
library(sf)  
library(leaflet)

nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) |>
  st_transform(st_crs(4326)) |>
  st_cast('POLYGON')

centroids <- st_centroid(nc)

I want to make a matrix and data frame that contains the distance from all centroids to all centroids:
### Option 1: Regular Distance
# data frame
dist_matrix <- st_distance(centroids, centroids) %>%
    units::set_units(km)  

dist_df <- expand.grid(from = nc$NAME, 
                       to = nc$NAME) %>%
    mutate(distance = as.vector(dist_matrix))

# matrix
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

nc$unique_id <- paste(nc$NAME, nc$FIPS, sep="_")

centroids <- st_centroid(nc)

dist_matrix <- st_distance(centroids, centroids) %>%
    units::set_units(km)  

dist_matrix <- as.matrix(dist_matrix)
rownames(dist_matrix) <- nc$unique_id
colnames(dist_matrix) <- nc$unique_id



# Option 2: Haversine Distance

haversine_distance <- function(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2, r = 6371) {
  lon1 <- lon1 * pi / 180
  lat1 <- lat1 * pi / 180
  lon2 <- lon2 * pi / 180
  lat2 <- lat2 * pi / 180
  
  dlon <- lon2 - lon1
  dlat <- lat2 - lat1
  a <- sin(dlat/2)^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)^2
  c <- 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
  
  d <- r * c
  return(d)
}

centroids_coords <- st_coordinates(centroids)

n <- nrow(centroids_coords)
dist_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n)

for(i in 1:n) {
  for(j in 1:n) {
    dist_matrix[i,j] <- haversine_distance(
      lon1 = centroids_coords[i,1],
      lat1 = centroids_coords[i,2],
      lon2 = centroids_coords[j,1],
      lat2 = centroids_coords[j,2]
    )
  }
}

rownames(dist_matrix) <- nc$unique_id
colnames(dist_matrix) <- nc$unique_id

dist_df <- expand.grid(from = nc$NAME, 
                      to = nc$NAME) %>%
    mutate(distance = as.vector(dist_matrix))

In reality, I am going to be doing this with a much bigger data et, e.g. all of Canada (https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/catalogue/92-179-X, https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/geo/sip-pis/boundary-limites/files-fichiers/lfed000b21a_e.zip) .
Is there something I can do to improve the efficiency of this code?

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.utf8    

time zone: America/Toronto
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sf_1.0-16

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] s2_1.1.6           digest_0.6.35      fastmap_1.2.0      xfun_0.45          magrittr_2.0.3    
 [6] e1071_1.7-14       KernSmooth_2.23-24 knitr_1.47         htmltools_0.5.8.1  rmarkdown_2.27    
[11] wk_0.9.1           classInt_0.4-10    cli_3.6.2          grid_4.4.1         DBI_1.2.3         
[16] proxy_0.4-27       class_7.3-22       compiler_4.4.1     rstudioapi_0.16.0  tools_4.4.1       
[21] evaluate_0.24.0    Rcpp_1.0.12        yaml_2.3.8         rlang_1.1.4        units_0.8-5 


Please provide nc so your question is reproducible.

Hmm.. st_distance() calculates the distance using great circle per default for geodetic coordinates, see help: great circle distance calculations use by default spherical distances (s2_distance or s2_distance_matrix); if sf_use_s2() is FALSE, ellipsoidal distances are computed using st_geod_distance which uses function geod_inverse from GeographicLib (part of PROJ); There is no need to create function for it. If you would use s2::s2_distance_... function(s),, you can even specify the radius.

@Friede: : nc is a default shapefile included in the sf library in R

I get > library(sf) > centroids <- st_centroid(nc) Error: object 'nc' not found ;)

@Friede: my sincere apologies - please see the updated R code in the question. Once again, my apologies.

Wouldn't work either. I edited.

Hmm... I included the sessionInfo in my question , maybe this will be helpful?

Is performance really an issue here? There are just 338 features in lfed000b21a_e , it took ~7s on a not-so-recent Core i7 laptop to get from archived SHP to pivoted distances.

@user430997, @Friede: dataset nc doesn't ship with {sf} (any more), see data(package = 'sf'). I resorted to spatial dataset nz (New Zealand provinces) from {spData} in below example.

What about:

    library(sf)
    library(spData)
    library(tidyr) ## no need to load the whole tidyverse
    
    centroids <- st_centroid(nz) # New Zealand provinces
    
    cbind(from = centroids$Name,
          data.frame(units::set_units(st_distance(centroids), 'km')) |> 
            setNames(nm = centroids$Name)
    ) |> 
      pivot_longer(-from, names_to = 'to')


output:

    # A tibble: 256 × 3
       from      to                value
       <chr>     <chr>              [km]
     1 Northland Northland            0 
     2 Northland Auckland           157.
     3 Northland Waikato            317.
     4 Northland Bay of Plenty      398.
     5 Northland Gisborne           478.
     6 Northland Hawke's Bay        502.
     7 Northland Taranaki           428.
     8 Northland Manawatu-Wanganui  494.
     9 Northland Wellington         636.
    10 Northland West Coast         846.
    # ℹ 246 more rows
    # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows


Edit
For geodetic distance, you can use st_geod_distance of package {lwgeom}. You might need to convert from projected to geographic coordinates with st_transform before.
